# add label column which is higher between two retrieved PID sum(amount)

Tags: mysql, sql

how do you add an additional label column to label which is higher between two retrieved `sum(amount)` value

the code works fine without the `CASE` statement but i want to add an additional label column

```
select p.product, sum(s.amount) as 'Total Sales'
CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT sum(s.amount) FROM sales WHERE s.pid = 'P01') > (SELECT sum(s.amount) FROM sales WHERE s.pid = 'P06')
            THEN 'Milk is higher'
        WHEN (SELECT sum(s.amount) FROM sales WHERE s.pid = 'P06') > (SELECT sum(s.amount) FROM sales WHERE s.pid = 'P01')
            THEN 'Eclairs is higher'
END AS WhichIsHigher
from sales s
join products p on s.pid=p.pid
where p.pid in ('p01','p06')
group by p.product;
```

below is data from `sales` table
[image]

below is data from `products` table

[image]

expected output is

[image]

Comment: You need to add all labels one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be summing `CASE` expressions:

```sql
SELECT
    p.product,
    SUM(s.amount) AS `Total Sales`,
    CASE WHEN SUM(s.amount) > 0.5 * SUM(SUM(s.amount)) OVER ()
         THEN p.product END AS WhichIsHigher
FROM products p
INNER JOIN sales s
    ON s.pid = p.pid
WHERE p.pid IN ('P01', 'P06')
GROUP BY p.product;
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the code, i tried it but it is labeling both retrieve rows as higher, `Milk` has a `Milk is higher` label same with `Eclairs` has a `Eclairs is higher` label